# Bad parameter combination with ec2 & test-kitchen

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to run test kitchen using the ec2 plugin in our VPC and getting the following message:

`Message: InvalidParameterCombination => The parameter groupName cannot be used with the parameter subnet`

As soon as I set the subnet_id to denote it's in the VPC i get the groupName error.

Here's my .kitchen.yml
I've not set groupName anywhere.

`driver:
  name: ec2
  aws_access_key_id: <%= ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] %>
  aws_ssh_key_id: ***
  ssh_key: <%= *** %>
  security_group_ids: ["default-server"]
  region: eu-west-1
  availability_zone: eu-west-1a
  require_chef_omnibus: true
  subnet_id: subnet-***
  iam_profile_name:
  ami_id: ami-***
  image_id: ami-***
  flavour_id: t2.micro
  assoicate_public_ip: true
  ebs_delete_on_termination: true`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your VPC security group as an ID rather than as a name.

```
security_group_ids: ["sg-xxxxxxx"]
```

Also, make sure the security group is assigned to a VPC.

Comment: figured out I wasn't using master, but rather the year old gem. Seems to have fixed it for now. Now I've just got to figure out why it *always* gets a public ip address even when set to false.